# Switching between viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My WPF application has 3 models and each has its own viewmodel & view.

How do I switch between these views on the main window based on menu selection?

Answer (score 2):

Switching VMs is not the route to go mostly due to data binding. Each page should have its own VM. That doesn't mean you can't share VMs though. Have the main page VM have each other VM, then when you switch, take that change into account with the data bindings.

Comment: I'd also add that you could use a `TabControl`, one TabItem for each `Page`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using view models, I will assume that you are using MVVM.

One way is to create a base class for your view models and then create a property of this type in your main view model, or your code behind of your `MainWindow.xaml` file. Different people would do this different ways and I wouldn't be surprised to see negative comments at even the mere suggestion of using your code behind... either way, it's up to you where you put it.

If all of the view models extend this base view model, then you will be able to set any of them as the value for this property. You can set up basic `DataTemplate`s for each view model type in `App.xaml` that will connect the views to the view models... again, there are several ways to do this, but this is my preferred way:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
    <Views:MainView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:UsersViewModel}">
    <Views:UsersView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you can simply link the `MenuItem` objects to `Command` objects in this main view model. In these `Command`s, you can simply set the relevant view model to be the value of the `ViewModel` property and the views will automatically update.